# Como fazer update corretamente php

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados, sql-update

Olá estou fazendo um painel administrativo onde que o administrador pode editar o Nome,Usuario e email porém ele nao realiza o UPDATE no banco de dados mas na mensagem fala que foi feito o update segue o codigo do Update.

```
<?php
    include_once("conexao.php");
    $servidor = "fdb17.atspace.me";
    $usuario = "2443930_braban";
    $senha = "minhasenha";
    $dbname = "2443930_braban";

    //Criar a conexao
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);

    //selecionando o banco de dados
    $db = mysqli_select_db($conn, "2443930_braban");

    //criando a query de consulta à tabela criada
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM usuarios") or die(
        mysqli_error($conn) //caso haja um erro na consulta
    );

    $id                 = $_POST["id"];
    $nome               = $_POST["nome"];
    $email              = $_POST["email"];
    $usuario            = $_POST["usuario"];

    $result_usuario = "UPDATE usuarios set nome ='$nome', usuario = '$usuario', email = '$email', WHERE id='$id'";

    $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
?>
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        if (mysqli_affected_rows($conn) != 0 ){ 
            echo "
                <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=http://braban.atspace.tv/dados/admin/ccbo/adm2/administrativo.php?link=2'>
                <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"Usuário editado com Sucesso.\");
                </script>
            ";         
        }
        else{   
            echo "
                <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=http://braban.atspace.tv/dados/admin/ccbo/adm2/administrativo.php?link=2'>
                <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"Usuário não foi editado com Sucesso.\");
                </script>
            ";
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dica : Abaixo do seu mysqli_query adicione printf("Error mensagem: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn)); Qual mensagem que dá ?

Comment: nao da mensagem de erro fala que Usuário editado com Sucesso mas nao edita nada

Comment: Adicionou o printf com o mysqli_error($conn) após a execução de sua querie ?

Comment: $result_usuario = "UPDATE usuarios set nome ='$nome', usuario = '$usuario', email = '$email', WHERE id='$id'"; não tem virgula após o ", email = '$email', WHERE" . Tira essa virgula!

Comment: adicionei rafael nao mostrou nenhum erro e tirei a vergula agora mostra Usuário não foi editado com Sucesso.

Comment: Então quando é assim e deixa agente perdido, geralmente antes da query mandamos imprimi-la dessa forma : 
echo "UPDATE usuarios set nome ='$nome', usuario = '$usuario', email = '$email', WHERE id='$id'"; pegamos o resultado e rodamos direto dentro do banco, deve ter alguma variável enviada por POST vazia como o $id; o mysql_error deveria reportar erro na querie.Manda imprimir a querie na pagina e verifica o resultado.

Comment: se eu colocar um SESSION vai funcionar seria?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82341/discussion-between-rafael-salomao-and-mateus-silva).